# Repeat function for results from a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a mysql database with 2 clips in it.
This is the code which show me the clip

```
if( $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Widget FROM clipuri WHERE Data='$data[mday].$data[mon].$data[year]'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`
```

And that code show the clip in html

```
<table border="0">
    <tr><td><?php echo $row['Widget'];  ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

How to make a repeat function to show me all clips from that database?!

Comment: Can you edit your question and show sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a while loop in your code.

```
    echo '<table border="0">';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
              echo '<tr><td>'.$row['Widget'].'</td></tr>';
            }//while

     echo '</table>';
```

Get all rows with while loop and echo them.

**3 in a row:**

```
$counter = 0;
echo '<table border="0">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
          if($counter % 3 == 0)
          {
            echo '<tr>';
          }
          $counter++;
          echo '<td>'.$row['Widget'].'</td>';
         if($counter % 3 == 0)
          {
            echo '/<tr>';
          }
        }//while

 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array(): Error while reading a row in C:\wamp\www\home.php on line 16 on line 16 i have the while function

Comment: So it seems your result set has some problems? Are you sure it's not empty?

Comment: It's working. I had closed the conection before the loop, sorry, i'm novice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mark as and answer if this solved your problem. You're welcome ;)

Comment: Can i set a limit of td in that table? For example i want 3 clips on a collon.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
...
}
```